# Entity framework, automatically link to existing entity on insert

Tags: entity-framework

I'm not sure if this is possible but I am inserting a lot of entities into the database, and for each item it has say a language property which is an entity. Currently I create a new language object for each item that is being inserted but this is just for testing as it creates a lot of duplicates. The languages should be unique in the database and should just point to an existing language record, the only way I can think of is to do seperate service calls for every insert to lookup a language code and get the id of the existing language which is a lot of overhead.

Is there a way for it to automatically lookup a record based on the language code and use that record?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially trying to match on a custom value rather than the id/primary key value. Wondering if there's a configuration setting for this

Comment: This appears on the surface to be a database normalization step in which there is a table of language objects and any insertion of data that is using that language object would just use the language object table key as a foreign key.  Can you create a kind of hash that will uniquely identify each of the different possible language objects and then use the hash when inserting new language objects into the language object table and when inserting the other data you would use the language object hash?

Comment: Do you know language codes up front? Is the language code a key on the language entity and a foreign key on the related entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `ObjectContext` and `DbContext` have methods that try to find an already loaded entity from the context in memory - `GetObjectByKey` for `ObjectContext` and `Find` for `DbContext`. Using these methods you avoid to load a `Language` entity more than once from the database.

Both methods need a primary key value as input parameter to lookup the entity by key. Essentially think of these methods as accessing an internal dictionary that relates the primary key to the entity object.

Now, refering to your comment...

> Essentially trying to match on a custom value rather than the
>   id/primary key value.

...you can't use these methods because they rely on knowing the primary key value you want to lookup.

What I would do is to mimic the logic of the mentioned internal dictionary by your own dictionary that relates your "custom value" to the entity instead of the primary key. I assume that the custom value is unique in the `Language` table.

So, the idea would be:

Given you have entities like this...

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    // ... more
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }             // primary key value
    public string CustomValue { get; set; } // the unique custom value
    // ... more
}
```

...and you have a collection of data you are using to insert the new entities...

```
public class Data
{
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCustomValue { get; set; }
    // ... more
}

var dataList = new List<Data>
{
    new Data { SomeOtherValue = "A", LanguageCustomValue = "EN" },
    new Data { SomeOtherValue = "B", LanguageCustomValue = "FR" },
    new Data { SomeOtherValue = "C", LanguageCustomValue = "EN" },
    new Data { SomeOtherValue = "D", LanguageCustomValue = "EN" },
    // ... more
}
```

...then you could use this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Language>();
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        Language language;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(data.LanguageCustomValue, out language))
        {
            // load the language only once from the database
            language = context.Languages.SingleOrDefault(l =>
                l.CustomValue == data.LanguageCustomValue);
            dict.Add(data.LanguageCustomValue, language);
        }

        var myEntity = new MyEntity
        {
            SomeOtherValue = data.SomeOtherValue,
            Language = language
        };

        context.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);  // or AddObject
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This would load only one `Language` entity per `LanguageCustomValue`, do this only once and doesn't create duplicates of `Language` objects in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean here, but if its during an insert, you'd generally check if it exists, and add it if it doesn't. You could store the languages in context if your inserting a bunch of entities. Not sure if this is the best solution though. Don't think there's a fast way to find an object in the store or context without a key. Depending on the complexity of you Language entity, you could cast the context 'languages' variable below *ToDictionary()* and roll through that instead.

```
//'db' is your context here.
var languages = db.Languages.all();
myentity MyEntity = new MyEntity();
myentity.property1 = "mynewvalue1";

var newlang = new Language{ LanguageName= "newlanguagename"};
//language exists?
if (!languages.Any( u => u.LanguageName== newlang.LanguageName ))
 {

  // no:
  db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(newlang);
  db.SubmitChanges();
  myentitly.Language = newlang;
 }
else{

  //yes:
  myentitly.Language = languages.Where( u => u.LanguageName== newlang.LanguageName).Single();
 }

db.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(myentity);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are concerned with overhead performance costs, I would suggest this as the most efficient way to process this:

**Step 1: Make sure your Languages table is correct.**

I'm not sure how you define which languages are used, so I can't help you here, just make sure that your language tables contains all needed rows.
Let's assume your table is as follows:

```
{ Id: 1 ; Language: "English" }
{ Id: 2 ; Language: "French"  }
{ Id: 3 ; Language: "German"  }
```

**Step 2: Processing your entities**

Step 2.1: Create a `Dictionary<string, int>` to easily map your Language table:

```
var lang_list = new Dictionary<string, int>();

using(var db = new DbContext()
{
     foreach(var row in db.Languages.ToList())
     {
            lang_list.Add(row.Language, row.Id);
     }
}

//From now on, you can refer to the local list.
```

Step 2.2: Adding the correct language to the (to be added) entity

I don't know how you will determine which language you need to add. let's assume you have a string variable `myLanguage` which contains the string name of the language you need.

You'll probably want to use something like:

```
int foundvalue;

if(lang_list.TryGetValue( myLanguage , out foundvalue ))
{
     //if language is in the list, the value (= the id of the row in the language
     // table) will be stored in foundvalue
     myEntity.LanguageId = foundvalue;
}
else
{
     //if the language wasn't found in the list, set a default lang (e.g. English)
     myEntity.LanguageId = 1;
}
```

I hope this helps you with your problem?

The benefits of using this process:

- You only have to query the database once for the Languages. After the list is populated, it will be stored in memory, which is a better method performance-wise.
- If an entity has an unexpected or incorrect language set, you will be able to fall back on a default language.

Comment: Footnote: Step 2.1: the foreach loop can be shortened to `lang_list = db.Languages.ToDictionary(row => row.Language, row => row.Id);` but this is a little harder to understand so I opted for the most readable version.